# Angular / Spring Boot / Azure Ingress - URL rewriting

Tags: angular, azure, url, spring-boot

I use Angular as frontend technology, spring boot for the backend and Azure Ingress as webserver.
My problem is that when the user refreshes the site there comes an 404 error because of Angular routes. 
I wonder if this approach to solve this problem is a good practice and if there may araise any problem with my own AJAX calls:

```
@Configuration
class WebApplicationConfig
{
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer()
    {
        return container -> {
            container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
        };
    }
}
```

?

#### Edit

What I am searching for is some kind of URL rewriting (e.g. on Apache webserver) for my technology stack.
Currently there is a static folder in the JAR file that is returning my Angular files. If the link is requested
always the angular files (index.html and dependencies) are returned but while the user is working the URL changes (only in frontend) and if he then
hit site refresh there comes an 404 error.

e.g.

http://somehost/some/static/url/ <-- OK

http://somehost/some/static/url/and/angular/route <-- 404

So I wonder if the solution above would be a good one. Or maybe there is another better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your Angular app is directly served by your Spring Boot app. If you want to stick with this solution (avoiding a separate web server) you will have to make sure that Spring Boot serves the `index.html` of your Angular app under any route (except those intended for API of course), as stated by Mixalloff.

Here is how I did it in a project:

- Put the Angular project as a sub-project in your Maven project, let's say in `src/main/frontend`. So if you build the Angular app you will get its static resources in the folder `src/main/frontend/dist`.
- Use the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy only the `index.html` generated in `src/main/frontend/dist` to the output directory `target/classes/templates`. So there should be the file `target/classes/templates/index.html` in the end.
- Use the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy any other static resources (like JavaScript, CSS, etc.) from `src/main/frontend/dist` to the output directory `target/classes/static`. This is where your files are also located currently.
- Include a cheap template engine into your Spring Boot app, e.g. use the `spring-boot-starter-mustache` to get Mustache auto-configured as your template engine for Spring MVC. We will use the `index.html` generated for your Angular app as a Mustache template.
- Create a Spring controller with a method returning the `index` view name for any path. Note the request mapping to `/**` here:

  ```
  @Controller
  public class IndexPageController {
    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public String index() {
      return "index";
    }
  }
  ```

The wildcard method returning the index page is automatically sorted last by Spring MVC, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison

So you can still add more controllers mapped to more specific paths, e.g. `/api/v1/whatever`.

In the end, your Spring Boot app will always return the `index.html` file for any route that does not match a more specific request mapping.

And this comes with even more sugar: Since the `index.html` is processed as a Mustache template it can contain server-side template markup if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like it because it provides less complexity and even more functionality than originally proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular is independently determine routes and must manage the display of 404 Page and another pages. You need always give away index.html file for all requests in your server